# Dealing with missing data during interpolation of daily temperature time-series

Tags: time-series, rstudio, interpolation, geospatial, raster

I intend to get a multiband time series raster of daily temperature. Thus, I am interpolating a daily-temperature.cvs time series [1980-2018] via idw+linear regression methods. The code below is meant to develop 14245 timesteps, each for a day. However, the interpolation stops around the timestep 731. i.e. I only get raster files from 01-01-1980 to 31-12-1981. Reviewing the database.cvs, I find that I have no values of temperature in 01-01-1982. So, I think that is the reason why the loop stops with the following message: "error in gstat.formula(d$formula, d$data) : 
  no response variable present in formula". My questions are i) how can I bypass missing values during the interpolation or ii) include a raster grid for days with no values to keep both the timeframe sequence and the interpolation process, and later get the stack of the raster time series?

I am new in spatial analysis with R so I do not have much idea about how to address or solve this issue.

## Loop for the interpolation

```
begin_date = as.Date("1980-01-01")
end_date = as.Date("2018-12-31")
all_dates<- seq(begin_date, end_date, 1)
for (i in 1:length(all_dates)) {
selected_date<- all_dates[i]
```

## Estimate a linear regression model of temperature ~ elevation

`model<- lm(Valor~Altitud, datapoints)
datapoints$res<- model$residuals
plot(Valor~Altitud, datapoints)
abline(model)`

## Calculate temperature value raster using the previous linear model

```
a<- model$coefficients[1]
b<- model$coefficients[2]
regression_grid<- a+r*b
```

## subsetting the database according the selected_date

```
dtbs<- subset(datapoints, datapoints$Fecha ==selected_date)
```

## interpolate the residuals using idw

```
idw_test<- idw(res~1,dtbs, defaultgrid)
```

## add regression grid and residuals

```
final_grid<- regression_grid + residual_grid
```

## Construct each filename

```
outname<- sub(pattern = ".tif", replacement = final_grid,
x=selected_date)
```

## export the raster files

```
r<- writeRaster(final_grid, file.path="~/ERA_CORPOCHIVOR/daily_temperature/grids/", filename = outname, "GTiff", ".tif", overwrite=T)
}#end of the for loop
```